# Cleanup handlers when controller is destroyed

Tags: angularjs

In angular, I have controllers for each one of my routes.

Say I set up a listener in my controller body:

```
$rootScope.$on 'myEvent', console.log
```

Do I need to dispose of this event handler if I navigate off the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You *do* have to deregister your event handler.

You'll get a deregistration function returned when you register the event.

---

From [the docs on `$on`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24on):

> Returns a deregistration function for this listener.

Comment: What callback do I use to do this? Route change start?

Comment: @ChristianStewart - Do it in `$routeChangeSuccess`.

Comment: Actually I think it's proper to do it in $destroy since the controller might not actually be destroyed.

Comment: @ChristianStewart - Unless you're using `ui-router` or some other 3rd party routing system, I'm not sure how your route might change without it destroying your controller.